# NodeMailer: Can not use IPv4 addresses with current network

Tags: ubuntu, nodemailer

I have using nodemailer to send emial notification in my system, and it works perfect before this week. I got an error said cannot use IPV4 address with current network

```
{ Error: Can not use IPv4 addresses with current network
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.dns.lookup [as callback] (/home/****/backend/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js:203:35)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:80:8) code: 'EDNS', command: 'CONN' }
```

Some info related to my system and application:
System: Ubuntu 22.04.
Backend: express.js.
Node.js version: 10.19.0.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
user: '**',
pass: '**',
},
});

function sendEmail(to, subject, text, html) {
transporter.sendMail({
from: '"Server - donotreply" <mailto:*******@gmail.com>', // sender address
to: to, // list of receivers
subject: subject, // Subject line
text: text, // plain text body
html: html, // html body
}).then(info =\> {
console.log({info});
}).catch(console.error);
}
```

I have no idea what is going on, can anyone please provide some info that can helps me figure out. thanks a lot

i have ried to restart the application and reboot the system, but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found answer for the problem, but i found a posible solusion to solve it.

Try reinstall the nodemailer - use `npm install all`

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem only on Windows and when the internet connexion of the computer was sharing from a smartphone.

In my side, the latest working `nodemailer` version was 6.7.3.

This issue was fixed in `nodemailer` 6.9.0 released on the 12 january 2023.

For me, the accepted solution does not works until the `nodemailer` v6.9.0 release in january..

So, the correct fix will be to update `nodemailer` to v6.9.0 or upper.